# read characters of an array that is allocated on free store

Tags: c++, pointers

I am doing a book for c++ and there is question that requires to make a program that read characters from **cin** into an array that you allocate on the free store.
It further asks to read individual characters until an exclamation mark is entered.
I am new to pointers and I dont know how to do this.
It also prohibits the use of std:: string and tells me not to care about memory exhaustion.
Please help!!!

Comment: Doesn't the book also explain how to do this?

Comment: well, if you're talking about dynamic arrays, you can use std::vector<>. Read characters, check for ! mark and then put the entry into the vector

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One step at a time.

Allocating an array on the free store:

```
char * ptr_char_array = new char[SIZE];
```

Reading characters into the array:

```
unsigned int chars_remaining = SIZE;
char * p = ptr_char_array;
while ((chars_remaining > 0) && (cin >> *p++))
{
  --chars_remaining;
}
```

To stop the reading when an exclamation point is read:

```
char c;
while ((chars_remaining > 0) && (cin >> c))
{
  if (c == '!')
  {
     break;
  }
  *p = c;
  ++p;
  --chars_remaining;
}
```

A better method is to use `std::string`, `std::vector` and `std::getline`, which I leave as research for the OP.

Comment: Thanks a lot...can you also tell me why did tell me not to care about memory exhaustion...

Comment: I have already answered a post today about reading into dynamic array; that is, reallocating the array when it fills up.  Please clarify "memory exhaustion".